# Finding LEAST/GREATEST values from combined COLUMNS, ignore 0 & NULL- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I've got a dataset with a bunch of rows for monthly salary payments for each account. we have 6 columns for this -

Salary_1, Salary_2, Salary_3, Salary_4, Salary_5 and Salary_6.

Sometimes salaries 3, 4, 5, 6 and occasionally 2 aren't populated, sometimes none are populated because they're unemployed. In this case, we have 0 in the field.

What I need to do is combine all salaries and find the MAX and MIN from these columns ---

```
   Select

        Greatest(Salary_1, Salary_2, Salary_3, Salary_4, Salary_5, Salary_6) as MaxSal, 
        Least(COALESCE(Salary_1, Salary_2, Salary_3, Salary_4, Salary_5, Salary_6),0) as MinSal

from

    (select
     sal1 as Salary_1, Select sal2 as Salary_2, Sal3 as Salary_3, sal4 as Salary_4, Sal5 as Salary_5, Sal6 as Salary_6
     from ....)a
```

The problem is, this is returning the correct value for Max Sal but 0.00 for Min, because it is the minimum value but won't let me ignore 0s, but in this case 0 is not a minimum salary value I want, I need the second lowest value here.

I've tried setting the original Sal1-Sal6 values to NULLIF 0 and it returns NULL for max and 0 for Min.

What else could I have a look at? the COALESCE combined with NULLIF has not worked for me which is what has been recommended on previous questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greatest and Least do not ignore nulls like aggregation functions do; you'll need to do something to avoid them. One option is something like this:

```
Greatest(IFNULL(Salary_1 ,0), ...)

Least(
     CASE WHEN Salary_1 IS NULL OR Salary_1 = 0 THEN /*some huge value*/ ELSE Salary_1 END
   , CASE WHEN Salary_2
   ....)
```

Comment: Note that you could use `Least(IFNULL(Salary_1 ,999999999), ...)`, too.  There's nothing special about LEAST() that requires a a CASE expression.

Comment: @BaconBits yes, but CASE supports the needed check for 0 (via AND), and support for CASE is a little more standardized across RDBMSes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be simplest to unpivot and aggregate the data:

```
select id, max(salary), min(salary)
from ((select id, salary_1 as salary from t) union all
      (select id, salary_2 as salary from t) union all
      . . .
     ) t
group by id;
```

This is definitely more expensive than a giant `case` expression.  On the other hand, it is less prone to error.

The real suggestion is to fix your data model.  Trying to store an array in multiple columns is generally a sign of a poor data model.  The more appropriate method would have one row per `salary` rather than putting them in separate columns.