# How to find the smallest value in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

i need help to *create a sql query that can find the smallest value in 1 row* , and display it in the last column, like this table.

| id | out | mid | in | Smallest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 100 | 50 | **50** |
| 2 | 100 | 150 | 50 | **50** |
| 3 | 200 | 100 | 250 | **100** |
| 4 | 50 | 100 | 150 | **50** |
| 5 | 50 | 100 | 100 | **50** |
| 6 | 20 | 200 | 100 | **20** |
| 7 | - | - | 100 | **100** |
| 8 | 150 | - | 100 | **100** |

this is my query :

Comment: `SELECT id,out,mid,in, MIN(out,mid,in) AS Smallest FROM table;`

Comment: `SELECT \`id\`, \`out\`, \`mid\`, \`in\`, LEAST( \`out\`, \`mid\`, \`in' ) FROM tbl`

Comment: @kmoser : i try to use that sql, but in the last id of the table i get wrong value is '-'/(null), correct is '100'

Comment: @TimRoberts i use that, but this sql is error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding LEAST/GREATEST values from combined COLUMNS, ignore 0 & NULL- MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822418/finding-least-greatest-values-from-combined-columns-ignore-0-null-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL you may use the scalar `LEAST()` function:

```sql
SELECT id, `out`, mid, `in`, LEAST(`out`, mid, `in`) AS Smallest
FROM yourTable;
```

If your database doesn't have a `LEAST` function, we can use a `CASE` expression as an alternative:

```sql
SELECT id, `out`, mid, `in`,
       CASE WHEN `out` < mid AND `out` < `in` THEN `out`
            WHEN mid < `in` THEN mid
            ELSE `in` END AS Smallest
FROM yourTable;
```

Side note: Both `IN` and `OUT` are reserved MySQL keywords, and you should avoid naming your columns with them.

Comment: This looks like it will have the same problem that OP pointed out with my earlier comment: namely, non-numeric values (specifically `'-'`) will prevent `LEAST()` from working properly. I suspect that in the actual schema, \`out\`, \`mid\`, and \`in\` are `VARCHAR`, not `INT`.